# Select Case, when no data return

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

it is possible do a SELECT CASE, decode, nvl or another query function when I need verify if the return of a select query is empty or has a value? 
For example, I have this:

```html
Record |  type  | id_customer
-------+--------+-------------
1      |    T   | cus1
2      |    A   | cus2
3      |    T   | cus3
4      |        | cus4
```

If I do this:

```
select decode(type,'T','Main','A','Adicional','none') from table where record=1;
```

I get Main.

If I fo this:

```
select decode(type,'T','Main','A','Adicional','none') from table where record=4;
```

I get none.

But if I do this:

```
select decode(type,'T','Main','A','Aditional','none') from table where record=5;
```

I get nothing, and is logic. So, I need get the decode value when the row exist and a text if the rows no exist.

So, I tried with SELECT CASE but is not posible get a value using COUNT. For example like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN count(1)>0 THEN decode(type,'T','Main','A','Aditional','none')
ELSE '-'
END
FROM TABLE WHERE record=5;
```

And get a ' - ', or the same if the record is 2, get 'Aditional'

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregate functions `min` or `max` outside expression:

```
select max(decode(type,'T','Main','A','Aditional','none')) 
from table
where record=5;
```

If query returns one row, you get value of that row. If query returns 0 rows, you get `NULL`.
Then you can replace `NULL` using `nvl`:

```
select nvl(max(decode(type,'T','Main','A','Aditional','none')), ' - ')
from table
where record=5;
```

**EDIT**
Also, if you need to choose one string from several:

```
select decode(max(decode(type,'T', 2, 'A', 1, 0)), 0, 'none', 1, 'Additional', 2, 'Main', null, ' - ')
from table
where record=5;
```

Comment: But what happen if the query is: select nvl(max(decode(type,'T','Main','A','Aditional','none')), ' - ')
from table
where record in (1,2);  ?? If the type is not numeric.

Comment: @h3g0r_ In this case, minimal and maximal values are calculated accordingly to this document: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51021. Which behavior do you need in the case of many rows?

Comment: Return type T or P instead A.

Comment: Get T  instead A and If the query returns 0 rows, get ' - '. For example if query is A,A,T,A  query must return T, only when are all A, the returns must A. Something like that. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @h3g0r_ And what this query returns now? I checked and got 'Main' (which means T, right?).

Comment: @h3g0r_ Also you can use double decode to get more predictable result: first use decode to convert letters T and A to numbers, then get max of it, then convert number to string... I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

This is an option:

```
select decode(type,'T','Main','A','Aditional','none') 
  from table 
 where record = 5
 union all
select '-'
  from dual 
 where not exists (select 1 from table where record = 5);
```

It selects records with `record` = 5 and unifies them with `'-'`, if no records exits with `record` = 5. Check out this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/039d4/3).

Comment: In Oracle10g, that result of total table rows of ' - ', because union all a thing that not exist is the total of the table. But If I add a rownum < 2 works fine, thank you. :)

Comment: Would a bracket resolve that as well? (as here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/039d4/10) I've only an Oracle 11R2 XE ...