# SQL - Return 0 When results are empty

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, coalesce, nvl

Using oracle 11g

How do I get 00000 when the results are empty. I have tried coalesce and nvl - not working.

```
 select lpad(movie_id, 5, '0') as MOVIE_ID from schema_A where movieB='642354';
```

Comment: what do you mean by *results are empty*?

Comment: no records happen because movieB=642354 does not exist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707937/select-case-when-no-data-return